# Join a column from a double nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to query a collection of products from products table that has a quantity of 3 or less
so I want to get a select result with all product data + a corresponding provider suggestion from Receipts table
as the image shows
[image: join diagram]
the corresponding provider should be queried in the following manner

1. search all products with less than 3 units left from "products"
   table
2. for each selected product go to "purchase" table and look
   for the last time I bought said product and get 'r_index' that
   corresponds to a Receipt
3. using the index return the provider name
4. join the provider name to the list of products from step 1

I wrote the next query that returns a single provider name corresponding to a product code

```
select provider from BuyingReceipts as r
inner join
(select top(1) r_index from purchase where code = 9) p
on r.r_index = p.r_index
```

but other than that I struggle to syntax a working join statement

Comment: Instead of Venn diagrams and an essay, could you please [create an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (table structure, a few rows of sample data, and desired results, e.g. using [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk))?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone seeing the question in the future that's how I did it

```
SELECT p.code, R.provider FROM purchase AS p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT provider, r_index FROM BuyingReceipts) R
ON p.r_index = R.r_index
INNER JOIN
(SELECT code FROM products WHERE quantity <= 3) s
ON p.code = s.code
```